"TimeoutException: Exception while reading from stream" during "dotnet ef database update" using Npgsql with PostgreSQL
I'm trying to update my PostgreSQL database using Entity Framework Core in a .NET application. However, when I run the command dotnet ef database update, I get a TimeoutException with the following stack trace.
Error message and stack trace:

Build started...
Build succeeded.
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
 ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer.g__EnsureLong|55_0(NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 count, Boolean async, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.g__OpenCore|213_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.UnpooledDataSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.g__OpenAsync|42_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrations()
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Migrations.Internal.NpgsqlMigrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)  
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Exception while reading from stream

Code sample of connection string:
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection" : "Host=MyIP; Port=6060; Database=test; Username=user; Password=password;"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    }
}

Versions I am using:

PostgreSQL: 15.7
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL: 8.0.10
.NET SDK Version: 8.0.403
OS: Windows 10

Things I have tried:

Checked the connection string – it seems correct
Pinged the PostgreSQL server – it responds (although with ping MyIP command, it shows "Request time out", I tried with Test-NetConnection (PowerShell) and it showed "TcpTestSucceeded : True", so no network issue I guess)
SSL settings – tried both with and without SSL
Increased command timeout – tried CommandTimeout=300 in connection string


Typically, the timeout comes from trying to connect to the sql server. Does your connection string include all the required keywords? (For example, I have seen 'server' instead of 'host' and 'port', 'Initial Catalog' instead of 'Database') .
Also, this may help - SQL Server connection string in Appsettings.json + .net Core 3.1

Hi, thanks for your response. This happened due to remote server configuration issue. It was solved from the other end. Now my system is connected to remote server. Thank you.
